# My device is trying to open mSecure app whenever I launch an internet browser

Tags: applications, security, browser

Whenever I launch an internet browser on my droid phone it attempts to launch another app (in my case mSecure).

This happens with dolphin and my stock browser so I don't think it's an mSecure setting.  In fact I deleted mSecure but I still get the message failure attempting to launch mSecure.

Any help to get rid of this message will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What version of Android do you have? Is it a stock version or a custom ROM? Are you rooted?

Answer (score 0):

[mSecure](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mseven.msecure) is a Password Manager and Digital Wallet. It contains a feature called [Auto-copy on URL Launch](https://msevensoftware.com/android_users_guide#Auto-copy_on_URL_Launch). Reinstall the app and untick all of its settings, maybe they kept somehow "active" for your browsers even after you uninstalled the app. Then uninstall the app if you still want to do it.

[image: mSecure Settings]

If neither the above nor the answers which other users post here work for you, the app manufacturer have an email to give you [support](https://msevensoftware.com/android_users_guide#Support). In that case, we encourage you to post here what they suggest you in order to fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I have a stock (unrooted) Jellybean OS (V4.1.1). I have attempted to uninstall and reinstall mSecure, without success. Even after I uninstall mSecure, the remnants of the problem exist, as I get a message 'unable to launch mSecure' whenever I open up a browser. I have also uninstalled and reinstalled Dolphin, but the problem still exists.

I have emailed mSecure, but they cannot help me.  There response was "We are not able to make our app do this, even if we wanted to. Apps are “sandboxed” and can’t affect other apps like that"

Comment: I also looked for a manifest file (.xml), but couldn't find one.  I know I can resolve this issue by doing a factory reset, but I'm hoping to try and understand what's going on before I take that drastic step.

Comment: Just to reiterate - this is happening with at least three browsers - Dolphin, Chrome and the stock browser, so it is almost certainly some setting / corruption in a service used by all browsers

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of Android, you might need to revoke the Device Administrator privilege for mSecure under the Security/Device Administrators setting.